# What is needed in my ARM template to add azure function?

Tags: c#, azure, deployment, octopus-deploy

I have an ARM template for my resource group. In there I have set up a Function App which is correctly deployed with my ARM template using Octopus Deploy (OD).

Now I have with C# developed an Azure Function which I want to be deployed into my Function App.

This can be done with a separate step (using a template) in OD and all seemed well when deploying... Except that it does not show up in my Function App in Azure as I expect it to.

Is there any further configuration in my ARM template I need to do? I haven't found anything on the subject, when deploying a c# azure function.

For a csx azure function it can be configured/deployed in the ARM template but it is not recommended for a c# azure function, what I read.

**EDIT:**
This is a part of my ARM template. The FunctionApp is created with the following resource.

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
  "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
  "name": "[parameters('sites_..._name')]",
  "location": "[parameters('location')]",
  "kind": "functionapp",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', parameters('serverfarms_..._name'))]",
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName'))]"
  ],
  "identity": {
    "type": "SystemAssigned"
  },
  "properties": {
    "enabled": true,
    "siteConfig": {
      "appSettings": [
        {
          "name": "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME",
          "value": "[parameters('runtimeStack')]"
        },
        {
          "name": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
          "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=',variables('storageAccountName'),';AccountKey=',listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName')), '2017-06-01').keys[0].value)]"
        },
        {
          "name": "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION",
          "value": "~2"
        },
        //...
        {
          "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING",
          "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', variables('storageAccountName'), ';AccountKey=', listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName')),'2017-06-01').keys[0].value)]"
        },
        {
          "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE",
          "value": "[parameters('sites_..._name')]"
        }
      ]
    },
    "hostNameSslStates": [
      {
        "name": "[concat(parameters('sites_..._name'), '.azurewebsites.net')]",
        "sslState": "Disabled",
        "hostType": "Standard"
      },
      {
        "name": "[concat(parameters('sites_..._name'), '.scm.azurewebsites.net')]",
        "sslState": "Disabled",
        "hostType": "Repository"
      }
    ],
    "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', parameters('serverfarms_..._name'))]",
    "reserved": false,
    "isXenon": false,
    "hyperV": false,
    "scmSiteAlsoStopped": false,
    "clientAffinityEnabled": false,
    "clientCertEnabled": false,
    "hostNamesDisabled": false,
    "containerSize": 1536,
    "dailyMemoryTimeQuota": 0,
    "httpsOnly": true,
    "redundancyMode": "None"
  }
}
```

As you can see I am registering my FunctionApp which after deployment of the ARM template AND separate deploy of my azure function TO that FunctionApp should include the azure function.

Though, the azure function do not show up under my FunctionApp.

Comment: ARM templates are used to create resources in Azure (or update the existing) but not to deploy code. Also, you can, for example, evaluate the [zip deploy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push) option, please refer for details to [Octopus site](https://octopus.com/blog/azure-functions).

Comment: @Sergey, yes. That I realized but question is, do I need any configuration in my ARMT to enable the Azure Function and show up within my Function App?

Comment: Well, basically (but not limited to) you should have declared `"type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms"` as an App Service plan, `"type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config"` as a configuration/parameters and `"type": "Microsoft.Web/sites"` for the Function App itself with `"kind": "functionapp"` value to exactly specify this is Function App, if I understand you correctly.

Comment: @Per Please share the necessary parts of your code (ARM template, deployment steps) or even better provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in order for us being able to reproduce your issue.

Comment: @DAXaholic Well, I am not sure if it is gonna help much to clear my question up, really. My question still remain... is there anything more I need to do in the ARM template? In addition to deploying the binaries to the FunctionApp.

Comment: @Sergey ...all the resources you mention are in the template.